# Assertion error when accessing pointer to pixels openCV

Tags: c++, pointers, opencv, image-processing

so I am struggling to understand why I am getting this assertion error from opencv when accessing a pointer in the next col/row of an image. Let me tell you what is happening and provide some code.

- I am taking a ROI from the image, which is a `cv::Mat` or a header to a section of a bigger `cv::Mat`.
- I constructed some pointers to access the value of my ROI. So lets say my ROI is filled with values of pixels and is a 3x3 Mat

  ```
      with the following Dimensions (index starting at 0,0)
      ---------
      | 1 | 2 | 3 |
      | 4 | 5 | 6 |
      | 7 | 8 | 9 |
  ```
- first of all I need to initialize my pointers to point to their positions respectively. I took the `ptr` function of the `cv::Mat` and their location in the grid via `cv::Point`.

Problem faced:

When I try to access the pixel of the next neighbor, I get an assertion error.

Diagnostics by me:

- I thought it might be the range, but I made sure that wouldn't be the case by defining the for loop conditions according to my dimensions.
- The item I am trying to access doesn't exist, but how I understand it when I go through the ROI, i already have the values in a new Matrix and I should be able to access all values around my desired pixels.

---

PART OF THE CODE:

```
        cv::Mat ROI =disTrafo(cv::Rect(cv::Point(x,y),cv::Size(3,3)));
        cv::minMaxLoc(ROI,&minVal,&maxVal,&minCoord,&maxCoord);
        auto* maxPtr_x = &maxCoord.x;
        auto* maxPtr_y = &maxCoord.y;
        auto* maxPtr_value = &maxVal;
        uchar diff1 = 0;
        uchar diff2= 0;
        uchar diff3 = 0;
        uchar diff4 = 0;
        uchar max_diff = 0;








        for(int j = 1; j < ROI.rows  ; j++){

            auto current = ROI.ptr<uchar>(maxCoord.y);
            auto neighbor_down = ROI.ptr<uchar>(maxCoord.y+1); //THE PROB IS HERE according to debugging
            auto neighbor_up = ROI.ptr<uchar>(maxCoord.y-1);

            cv::Point poi ; //point of interest


            for(int i= 0; i < ROI.cols; i++){


                switch(maxCoord.x){ //PROOF FOR LOGIC
                    case 0:
                        if(maxCoord.y == 0){ //another switch statement maybe ??

                            diff1 = std::abs(current[maxCoord.x+1] - current[maxCoord.x]);
                            diff2 = std::abs(neighbor_down[maxCoord.x] - current[maxCoord.x]);

                            if(diff2 > diff1){

                                cv::Point(maxCoord.x,maxCoord.y+1) = poi;

                            } else {

                                cv::Point(maxCoord.x+1,maxCoord.y) = poi;

                            }

                        };
```

ASSERTION FAILED when running it: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed(y == 0|| < data && dims >= 1 && (unsigned)y < (unsigned)size.p[0])) in cv::Mat::ptr, file //... indicates path to header file mat.hpp// line 428

I can't put my finger on the problem, could you please be of assistance. And please give me some knowledge when working with pointers and pixels in case I misunderstood something.

Thank you

Comment: Please post what kind of assertion failed (error message)

Comment: ASSERTION FAILED when running it: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed(y == 0|| < data && dims >= 1 && (unsigned)y < (unsigned)size.p[0])) in cv::Mat::ptr, file //... indicates path to header file mat.hpp// line 428 and VS throws it as cv::Exception

Comment: can you please `std::cout << maxCoord.y << std::endl`  before `auto current = ROI.ptr<uchar>(maxCoord.y);` and tell the last value?

Comment: do you change `ROI` or `maxCoord` within the loop`? otherwise you will always have the same values for current and neighbors in each iteration...

Comment: @Micka yes I do change the ROI, it is a "sliding window". Well i cant tell the value since I can't make the code run without a crash, the beginning maxCoord.y is 0 so it may be a fluke and I have indeed my maximum at the first row in my ROI.

Comment: that might be the problem, since you try to access `ROI.ptr<uchar>(maxCoord.y-1);` which would be row `-1` if `maxCoord.y == 0` but your debugging said that the problem-line is another one...

Comment: for(int j = 1; j < ROI.rows - 1  ; j++)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    for(int j = 1; j < ROI.rows  ; j++){

        auto current = ROI.ptr<uchar>(maxCoord.y);
        auto neighbor_down = ROI.ptr<uchar>(maxCoord.y+1); //THE PROB IS HERE according to debugging
        auto neighbor_up = ROI.ptr<uchar>(maxCoord.y-1);

        cv::Point poi ; //point of interest

         cv::Point bordess(Point(0,0));
        for(int i= 0; i < ROI.cols; i++){


            switch(maxCoord.x){ //PROOF FOR LOGIC
                case 0:
                    if(maxCoord.y == 0){ //another switch statement maybe ??

                        diff1 = std::abs(current[maxCoord.x+1] - current[maxCoord.x]);
                        diff2 = std::abs(neighbor_down[maxCoord.x] - current[maxCoord.x]);

                        if(diff2 > diff1){

                            cv::Point(maxCoord.x,maxCoord.y+1) = poi & bordess;

                        } else {

                            cv::Point(maxCoord.x+1,maxCoord.y) = poi & bordess;

                        }

                    };
```

Comment: my problem is it crashes before reaching your bordess point. So it is not very relevant in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so basically I figured out that my pointer definition was wrong due to the nature of the input image. I have done some preprocessing with the image and the ranges of the values inside changed from `uchar`to some other value. When I changed the `auto neighbor_down = ROI.ptr<uchar>(maxCoord.y+1);`for example to `auto neighbor_down = ROI.ptr<float>(maxCoord.y+1);` everything ran normal.